# Rerun behaviors

Tags: javascript

In order to output the SearchApiAutoCompleteFormBlock (view) within a modal, we lost the  bound JavaScript events on the input. In other words, the DOM element (`<div>`) for the block was recreated by JavaScript after Drupal adds the events.

Now we need to rebind the events for the autocomplete.

This is the behavior of the Search API autocomplete module.

```javascript
Drupal.behaviors.searchApiAutocomplete = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
  // Find all our fields with autocomplete settings.
  $(context)
    .find('.ui-autocomplete-input[data-search-api-autocomplete-search]')
    .once('search-api-autocomplete')
    .each(function () {
      var uiAutocomplete = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
      if (!uiAutocomplete) {
        return;
      }
      var $element = uiAutocomplete.menu.element;
      $element.addClass('search-api-autocomplete-search');
      var elementSettings = autocomplete.getSettings(this, settings);
      if (elementSettings['delay']) {
        uiAutocomplete.options['delay'] = elementSettings['delay'];
      }
      if (elementSettings['min_length']) {
        uiAutocomplete.options['minLength'] = elementSettings['min_length'];
      }
      // Override the "select" callback of the jQuery UI autocomplete.
      var oldSelect = uiAutocomplete.options.select;
      uiAutocomplete.options.select = function (event, ui) {
        // If this is a URL suggestion, instead of autocompleting we
        // redirect the user to that URL.
        if (ui.item.url) {
          location.href = ui.item.url;
          return false;
        }

        var ret = oldSelect.apply(this, arguments);

        // If auto-submit is enabled, submit the form.
        if (elementSettings['auto_submit'] && elementSettings['selector']) {
          $(elementSettings['selector'], this.form).trigger('click');
        }

        return ret;
      };
    });
}
```

I would expect there is some kind of mechanism to re-register view block contexts.
I have no idea if this can be done easily. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be misunderstanding, but if you've changed the DOM and want to re-bind behaviors, you normally just run `Drupal.attachBehaviors()`

Comment: Thanks Clive. I tried "Drupal.attachBehaviors()" before - it was not working due to a totally non dependent  issue. But your post helped as I rechecked the whole script and was able to find the issue.